# Does taking honey and apple cider vinegar lower blood pressure in humans?

Tags: natural-remedies, honey, livestrong, vinegar

[Livestrong](http://www.livestrong.com/article/308115-how-use-apple-cider-vinegar-to-lower-high-blood-pressure/) claim:

> You can now lower your blood pressure by consuming apple cider vinegar. Other herbs, foods and dietary changes can assist in increasing the effectiveness of the vinegar. You can take a shot of it diluted in water or use it as a seasoning on uncooked or lightly cooked foods. The reason why the vinegar is best uncooked is because it retains its nutrients and fermentation when not cooked above 116 degrees F.

I found this [Web MD](http://www.webmd.com/diet/apple-cider-vinegar?page=2) reference:

> Another study in rats found that vinegar could lower high blood pressure. A large observational study also found that people who ate oil and vinegar dressing on salads five to six times a week had lower rates of heart disease than people who didn't. However, it's far from clear that the vinegar was the reason.

But I cannot find a study on humans. So can taking a bit of apple cider vinegar a day lower blood pressure in humans?